# @Transactional with xml-defined bean not working. (OSGi)

Tags: java, spring, osgi, transactional

I can't get @Transactional annotation to work with xml-defined bean. I don't know if xml definition has anything to do with it. Maybe it's the issue with OSGi.

```
<bean id="myDao"
          class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
        <property name="target" ref="myDao_t"/>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_MANDATORY,
                    timeout_60,
                    -Exception
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When I specify a proxy with xml like above it works.

I have `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />` specified in the same bundle-context.xml where the bean definition is.

MyDao is just a simple class implementing interface with one method.

There is no exception, it just doesn't create proxy for myDao.

What might be missing?

```
<bean id="myPlanner" class="com.something.planner.MyPlanner">
     <property name="myDao" ref="myDao" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Show us how you inject `myDao` into the bean which uses it.

Comment: Which version of Spring?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Sorry, I forgot to mention, 2.5.6.A

Comment: For annotations, I'd use at least Spring 3.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: 
unfortunately updating is not an option.

Comment: Which version of Java do you use? From Java 8, I would suggest to define transaction blocks with Lambda expressions instead of annotations. With lambda expressions there are no problems within OSGi as no weaving, and interception tricks are necessary. If you use Java 8 and you are interested, I can show an example.

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos: In this particular project I'm using Java 5. However, I'm still curious to see Java 8 example.

Comment: @Thuam Pham: See https://github.com/everit-org/transaction-helper. With this solution, you must instantiate a TransactionHelper and pass the TransactionManager for it (TransactionHelper can be a Spring Bean). After that you can use it within your code with unnamed classes (before java 8) or with lambda expressions. You have the same propagation options as with Spring, but this solution does not use any trick so it works within OSGi for sure. Must mention that this works only with JTA, not custom Spring transaction handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. The class of the bean `myDao` should be `MyDao` (the type of the DAO instead of `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`).
2. Put the annotation `@Transactional` on each public method in `MyDao.java`.

Spring should then automatically create a proxy for you. The approach in your question looks like "I try to create and configure the proxy factory myself".

While there surely is away to do that, I don't know exactly how you would do that. Instead, I rely on `<tx:annotation-driven>` and the `@Transactional` annotation.

**EDIT** You're using Spring 2.5.6A.

I just checked and `@Transactional` was added with Spring 1.2. But I'm not sure when `<tx:annotation-driven>` was added. The related `EnableTransactionManagement` was added with 3.1.

But the XML element is in this schema: http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd so it should be available in 2.5.

Maybe you're missing the necessary AOP libraries (cglib) on the classpath?

Comment: That's what i did. The example i provided was to show what is working for me. When i'm trying to achieve this with MyDao type and @Transactional annotation and <tx:annotation-driven> proxy won't be created.

Comment: Check the classpath, and the log output. Look for errors in the log output and that Spring actually picks up the `<tx:annotation-driven>` element.

Comment: I'm not using cglib but myDao has an interface so it should use interface proxy. I'll look for any errors.

Comment: Do you have `<context:annotation-config />` in your XML as well? [According to the docs](http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd), it shouldn't be necessary but that's the only difference which I can see.

Comment: Tried that, makes no difference.

Comment: I looked at some code. Stuff like `ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration` is since Spring 3.1. So even though the XML elements are in the schema, I start to think that this only works for Spring 3.1 and up.